# Java GUI Repeatable Process

Tags: java, user-interface, loops, process

I recently took up Java and I decided to construct a mini rock paper scissors game. Although, I think it turned out working but badly designed it still has a small problem. I cannot seem to figure out how to make the whole process repeatable because I have to restart the program so that the computer can choose once again between rock, paper or scissors. This is my code:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;

    String AIGuess;
    String myGuess;

    boolean playAgain = true;

    JButton rock = new JButton("Rock");
    JButton paper = new JButton("Paper");
    JButton scissors = new JButton("Scissors");

    JLabel AIGuessDisplay = new JLabel(AIGuess);

    public Panel() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(rock);
        rock.addActionListener(
                  new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            myGuess = "Rock";
                            if (randomNum == 1) {
                                AIGuess = "Rock";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                            }
                            if (randomNum == 2) {
                                AIGuess = "Paper";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                            }
                            if (randomNum == 3) {
                                AIGuess = "Scissors";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                            }
                        }
                      }
                    );
        add(paper);
        paper.addActionListener(
                  new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            myGuess = "Paper";
                            if (randomNum == 1) {
                                AIGuess = "Rock";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                            }
                            if (randomNum == 2) {
                                AIGuess = "Paper";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                            }
                            if (randomNum == 3) {
                                AIGuess = "Scissors";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                            }
                        }
                      }
                    );

        add(scissors);
        scissors.addActionListener(
                  new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            myGuess = "Scissors";
                            if (randomNum == 1) {
                                AIGuess = "Rock";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                            }
                            if (randomNum == 2) {
                                AIGuess = "Paper";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                            }
                            if (randomNum == 3) {
                                AIGuess = "Scissors";
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                            }
                        }
                      }
                    );
        add(AIGuessDisplay);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

Comment: Side note: If you're just in the process of learning GUI programming with Java, I recommend to use JavaFX instead of Swing, since Swing is currently in maintenance mode and JavaFX is the designated successor.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing the `main` and setup of the panel, but basically, it seems that you only assign a value to `randomNum` once - at its declaration.

Therefore, that `randomNum` is not going to change, and thus the computer selection will be the same all the time.

You should therefore add a method, say `newComputerSelection()`, which will put a new random number in `randomNum`. And call this method from your action listeners before making your decisions.

In fact, you don't even have to have `randomNum` as a field. You can just get a new random number in that method, and immediately decide based on it what the `AIGuess` will be, instead of deciding inside each of the action listeners. In the action listeners, you just need to compare the user's choice to the `AIGuess` and decide if it's win, lose or tie.

Next step would be to eliminate `AIGuess` and just return the value of it from the `newComputerSelection` method. There are more improvements you can make, but basically, **you need to change the computer choice on each new turn**.

Comment: I did not think of that I cannot believe the answer was so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you just really want to avoid restarting your program to be able to play again, you can add a new JButton in your code below the  `add(AIGuessDisplay);`.

```
    add(AIGuessDisplay);

    JButton playAgain = new JButton("Play Again");
    add(playAgain);
    playAgain.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                randomNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;                            
            }
        }
    );        
}
```

That button will generate a fresh value for randomNum.

If you don't like adding a new JButton, another option to improve your program is to add the code `randomNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;` in **each** actionperformed as shown below so that the randomNum will have a new value everytime any button(Rock, Paper, or Scissor) is clicked.

```
new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        randomNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
```

but this modification differs now from how your program originally works.